# error loading json using topsy

Tags: json, python-2.7, twitter, topsy

When i load single record json is created just fine when i try to load multiple records i get this error. Sorry i am new to python http://tny.cz/ce1baaba

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TweetGraber.py", line 26, in <module>
    get_tweets_by_query(topic)
  File "TweetGraber.py", line 15, in get_tweets_by_query
    json_tree = json.loads(source)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 368, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 11 column 1 (char 2380 - 46974)
```

Here is my code

```
def get_tweets_by_query(query, count=10):
    """A function that gets the tweets by a query."""
    Tweets=[]
    queryEncoded=urllib.quote(query)
    api_key = "xxxxx"
    source=urllib.urlopen("http://api.topsy.com/v2/content/bulktweets.json?q=%s&type=tweet&offset=0&perpage=%s&window=realtime&apikey=%s" % (queryEncoded, count, api_key)).read()
    json_tree = json.loads(source)
    pprint(json_tree)
topic = raw_input("Please enter a topic: ")
get_tweets_by_query(topic)
```

Comment: Could you also post your generated JSON? The JSON parser is failing, so it looks like you JSON is malformed somehow.

Comment: Should i post a pastebin whould that be fine beacuse it seems long to me to be posted here

Comment: If you think it is too long you could either post a summarized example (shortest use case where it fails) or indeed a Pastbin link (less favorable).

Comment: I have added the link to json response http://tny.cz/ce1baaba

Comment: Your generated `JSON` is not hierarchical, you have two objects `{...}` side-by-side. They need to be wrapped in some kind of outer structure to be valid `JSON` (like and array `[...]`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Timusan I was able to correct my json The problem with the original it was missing the root element "[" which showed we are expecting array and there "," was missing after end of each object. So here is fixed code.
So here is the code

```
def get_tweets_by_query(query, count=10):
    """A function that gets the tweets by a query."""
    Tweets=[]
    queryEncoded=urllib.quote(query)
    api_key = "xx"
    source=urllib.urlopen("http://api.topsy.com/v2/content/bulktweets.json?q=%s&type=tweet&offset=0&perpage=%s&window=realtime&apikey=%s" % (queryEncoded, count, api_key)).read()
    source="["+source+"]"
    source=source.replace("}\n{","},{")
    json_tree = json.loads(source)
    pprint(json_tree)
```

Comment: Yes it solves the problem keep in mind it will resolve only json return of http://api.topsy.com/v2/content/bulktweets.json only.

Comment: Glad to hear that. But to make your own answer more useful for other people who might stumble upon it: make it more clear why this works. Explain a bit more what you did (what changed since the not working example).